# Как из MySql вывести в цикле php максимальное значение?

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть таблица( в таблице много полей) и есть поле под названием "popular". В поле хранятся значения популярности товара. Их много, начиная с 1 заканчивая 2000. У меня не получается вывести поочерёдно в цикле товары, начиная с максимального значения и заканчивая минимальным. Вот что я делал:

```
$res = "SELECT max(popular) FROM product";
$query = mysql_query($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
....
}
```

Либо другим способом

```
$res = "SELECT * FROM mesages ORDER BY popular DESC limit 12";
$query = mysql_query($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
....
}
```

У меня просто не работает сортировка... Подскажите пожалуйста, где я и в чём неправ...

Comment: Поле popular какие имеет параметры? TEXT, VARCHAR, INT

Comment: varchar(255)

Answer (score 3):

У тебя поле popular типа varchar, вот он и выводит 1, 12, 13, 2. Если значений будет больше, то получишь 1,11,12...2,20,21,... ну ты понял. установи тип int и будет тебе счастье на земле и на небесе=)

Comment: Спасибо, работает! :)

Comment: Живите долго и счастливо и хотя иногда включайте мозг. Чудес не бывает.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае вы выбираете максимальное значение `popular`, во втором, судя по всему, ищете не в той таблице.

Comment: Извиняюсь, непавильно таблицу просто указал. там вместо mesage - product..

Comment: Хм... тогда второй вариант должен работать. Разве что уберите limit 12, но тогда получите тормоза скрипта при большом количестве товаров.

Comment: При втором варианте у меня просто тупость какая то происходит! выборка происходит следующим образом: нсейчас там всего четыре товара,но со временем их будет много. сейчас там есть такие цифры: 12, 2, 13, 1. если испольозвовать второй вариант получается что он выбирает следующим образом: 1, 12, 13, 2. а мне надо чтоб было 1, 2, 12, 13......

Comment: > сейчас там есть такие цифры: 12, 2, 13, 1

Что это за цифры? Популярность товаров или их их идентификаторы?
Подозреваю второе. :-)

Comment: нет, вы ошиблись! идентификаторы там то тоже есть, но я то сортирую по полю популярности!)